# Django - Print Dictionary of List of Lists in a Table in HTML

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a Dictionary of List of Lists.
I want to print this as a structured way preferably a table.

For each hostname, i want its specified rows in the table with three columns (Address   Interface   State   ID ) with apprpriate entries printed out. It seems a very complicated nested loop if possible.

Here is the dictionary ospfdictkey being passed to the template

```
{'hostname': [['R1-ISP'], ['R2-ISP']], 'ospfneighboraddress': [['192.168.5.2', '192.168.5.13', '192.168.5.25'], ['192.168.5.1', '192.168.5.6', '192.168.5.32']], 'ospfneighborinterface': [['ae1.0', 'ae4.0', 'ae7.0'], ['ae1.0', 'ae2.0', 'ae9.0']], 'ospfneighborstate': [['Full', 'Full', 'Full'], ['Full', 'Full', 'Full']], 'ospfneighborID': [['172.0.0.2', '172.0.0.4', '172.0.0.5'], ['172.0.0.1', '172.0.0.3', '172.0.0.6']]}




HTML Code

    {% for ip in listip %}
      {% for ospfadd in ospfdictkey.ospfneighboraddress %}
      {% for a in ospfadd %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ a }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Here is the end result im getting
but its repeating keys data and how do i iterate over other keys to print next as table data ?

[image: Table in HTML]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't fully understand your question but here are some tips to refactor that.

1. You should be specific with template syntax. If it is a dictionary, try using dict.items

```
{% for key, value in dict.items %} 
    {{ key }}, {{ value }} 
{% endfor %}
```

2. You could use custom filters. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/ for more information. By writing your own filters you can use your dictionary on your intention using pure python (either doing something like dict['hostname'][0] for accessing first element from list of a **hostname** key in a dict). I wrote it roughly but hope you got the idea, if any questions don't hesitate to ask. Additionally, you could **filter** items in a list which is a value in your dictionary. For example:

```
if len(dictionary['hostname'] > 2: # if you want to get only those values which length is greater than 2
    # return something
```

PS. try to write readable code in your editor and in here asking questions like so:

```
{
  'hostname': [
     ['R1-ISP'],
     ['R2-ISP'],
   ], 
  'ospfneighboraddress': [
    ['192.168.5.2', '192.168.5.13', '192.168.5.25'],
    ['192.168.5.1', '192.168.5.6', '192.168.5.32'],
   ],
   ...
}
```